# Firebreath Cmake not found when cmake 2.8.8 is installed on MacOsX

Tags: macos, cmake, kinect, firebreath

When trying to build an xcode project with the following command line:
./firebreath/prepmac.sh projects/ build/

I get:
Using projects in: /Users/uwecerron/Desktop/Node/projects
Generating build files in: /Users/uwecerron/Desktop/Node/build
NOTE: The build files in /Users/uwecerron/Desktop/Node/build should *NEVER* be modified directly. Make changes in cmake and re-run this script.
~/Desktop/Node/build ~/Desktop/Node
./firebreath/prepmac.sh: line 10: cmake: command not found
CMake failed. Please check error messages

There are no error messages, and i have cmake 2.8-8 installed. Any suggestions on what to do? this is for a kinect project using depthjs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you installed cmake it would have ask you if you wanted to install the command line links; you probably accidentally told it not to. Install cmake again and tell it to install the command-line links and it should work fine.

Comment: This solution worked, Thank You! By any chance do you know of any cross browser extensions flexible enough to work with flash- RTMFP?

Comment: No, but as a general rule it's better not to ask questions in a comment; keep the comments for things relevant to the original question. Ask the other as a new question if you want.

Comment: For future visitors: now installer doesn't ask you that. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/23849962/2436687 for solutions.