# cmake installer for Mac fails to create /usr/bin symlinks

Tags: macos, command, cmake

Try to install CMake cmake-2.8.12.2-Darwin64-universal.dmg on OS X 10.9.3
I removed the old version from Application folder and delete ccmake, cmake, cmake-gui etc in usr/bin.
But get "Failed create symlink installation may be incomplete: /usr/bin/cpack" and other error messages.

Please let me know if any suggestion or question.

Thank you for precious time on my question.

Comment: You normally need root access for installations on Macs... I suggest you do `su` and enter the root password and then repeat the installation if it is Terminal-driven.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I tried to install cmake dmg from the command line by following this link.
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73926/is-there-a-command-to-install-a-dmg
But GOT "Error trying to locate volume at /Applications/"
Can I have one more suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: I think @ComicSansMS has made a great suggestion, run `ls -l /usr/bin | grep -i cmake` and remove all the links with `sudo rm /usr/bin/something`. Then re-try installing, but edit your question and update it with all the outputs you see so folks can assist you.

Comment: Sorry for the late update. With @ComicSansMS 's suggestion (remove all the links), then installation works!. Thank you ComicSansMS and Mark Setchell

Comment: Try this solution explained in this thread :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442096/cmake-2-8-10-installation-for-mac-os-x-fails-creating-symlinks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This tends to happen to me as well from time to time.

The problem is basically that the symlinks from the previous installation are not cleaned up when removing CMake from Applications and now the installer has trouble updating them to the new version.

The easiest fix here is to manually remove those links from `/usr/bin` and re-run the installer. IIRC it's at least `cmake`, `ccmake`, `cmake-gui`, `cpack` and `ctest` that need removing. Best way is to do a `ls -l /usr/bin` from the console and `grep` for all the links pointing to the old CMake installation directory.

Comment: Sorry, ComicSansMS. For some reason it still doesn't work. But thank you so much for suggestion!

Comment: Thanks; without commas, plus cmakexbuild: cd /usr/bin ; sudo rm cmake ccmake cmake-gui cpack ctest cmakexbuild

Answer (score 96):

CMake 3.0 does not seem to come with an installer any longer. So I ran into a similar issue. Like @ComicSansMS said you need to first remove the symlinks using `sudo rm`. Then you can run the gui with
`sudo /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/MacOS/CMake` and use the Tools -> Install For Command Line Use menu item.

From some new 3.x version you have to use this command to create symlinks:

```
sudo "/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake-gui" --install
```

Note option in menu now gives only this instruction and other possible choices.

Comment: This way worked for me. It seems like must use sudo to run it. It didn't work when I ran it from the Applications.

Comment: Really helpful! If the question hadn't asked specifically about v. 2.8.12.2 I would have suggested updating by making this the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

In the latest versions the **install procedure** is simple, in the terminal simply type:

```
sudo "/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake-gui" --install
```

And the soft links will be automatically generated.

Tested with `cmake version 3.3.2` and `cmake version 3.8.0`

---

If you fear you might have remaining links from a previous version you can remove them before installing the new version:

```
cd /usr/bin; sudo rm ccmake cmake cmake-gui cmakexbuild cpack ctest
```

---

Otherwise for older versions you should start the application with an account with admin privileges for the install to work. i.e.:

```
sudo /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/MacOS/CMake
```

Answer (score 18):

As said earlier, launch the GUI in sudo mode. Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/MacOS/CMake
```

then in the GUI, go to *Tools* menu and *Install For Command Line Use* and press the *Install Command Line Links* button. The terminal will show:

```
ln -s [/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/ccmake] [/usr/bin/ccmake]
ln -s [/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake] [/usr/bin/cmake]
ln -s [/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake-gui] [/usr/bin/cmake-gui]
ln -s [/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmakexbuild] [/usr/bin/cmakexbuild]
ln -s [/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cpack] [/usr/bin/cpack]
ln -s [/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/ctest] [/usr/bin/ctest]
```

and here you are.  Tested with cmake-3.1.0-rc2.

Comment: At least as of 3.3.0-rc3 the "Install For Command Line Use" menu no longer exists.

Answer (score 8):

There is a option in

```
Cmake GUI->Tools->How to install for command line use
```

which shows options

```
One may add CMake to the PATH:

 PATH="/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin":"$PATH"

Or, to install symlinks to '/usr/local/bin', run:

 sudo "/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake-gui" --install

Or, to install symlinks to another directory, run:

 sudo "/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake-gui" --install=/path/to/bin
```

In which first option worked for me.

Comment: Looks it's the one for ver 3.6.2

Answer (score 3):

In the CMake 3.3.0 there is no longer the option Install For Command Line. Below is how I did it.

I've downloaded the dmg file and copied to Applications folder. But I had to add the path to the binary to the PATH environment variable. This is the complete step-by-step.

1. Download CMake dmg from official website (http://www.cmake.org);
2. Open the dmg file. Copy the CMake executable to the Applications folder;
3. Open a terminal and type "cd ~" (to go to your home folder);
4. Open the file .bash_profile (if it does not exist, create it with "touch .bash_profile");
5. Inside .bash_profile file, insert the following line:

export PATH="/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/:$PATH"

(This will add the binary of CMake to yout PATH variable)

6. Save the .bash_profile file and exit;
7. Back to the terminal, type "source .bash_profile", to update the PATH variable.;
8. Ready to go! Try to compile again :)

The good part of adding it to PATH is that it will work every time you restart your computer.

Comment: You can use "cd" alone if you want to go your home folder.

Answer (score 3):

very simple,
install the .dmg file then open,

tools->How to install for Command line use

you can find:

One may add CMake to the PATH:

PATH="/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin":"$PATH"

Or, to install symlinks to '/usr/local/bin', run:

sudo "/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake-gui" --install

Or, to install symlinks to another directory, run:

sudo "/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake-gui" --install=/path/to/bin

Answer (score 1):

Opening the Applications folder in a terminal

```
cd /
cd Applications/
```

then doing:

```
sudo bash
CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake-gui
```

Then run from the CMake GUI:
 "Tools->Install For Command Line Use"

works OK for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install on OSX 10.11 it **needs** to be installed to /usr/local/bin ( just /usr/bin will not work! ). I couldn't get that to work with the cmake I had installed (3.2.1). After downloading the latest version (3.6.1) and using this commandline it worked. No need to go to the gui and click on 'install commandline tools', it just does it instantly.

note: it might also work without specifying /usr/local/bin on cmake-3.6.1 - haven't tested that.

```
sudo "/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake-gui" --install=/usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use sudo start cmake-gui, and choose folder to /usr/local/bin instead the default /usr/bin when install command line
I was success